# Remove WhiteSpace Chars from String instance

Tags: java, regex, string, trim

is there another way how to remove WhiteSpace Char(s) from String

1) other as I know

```
myString.trim()

Pattern.compile("\\s");
```

2) is there another reason(s) search/look for an another/different method as I using

Comment: You should write the literal character class; Java before 1.7’s `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASSES` flag is broken for Unicode whitespace.

Comment: @tchrist, did you mean "...`\s` is broken..."?

Comment: @Alan: Sorry. It doesn’t get stuff like `\xA0`.  I’ve seen a lot of that lately.

Comment: @tchrist: No, I meant there seems to be a typo in your comment; the word "`\s`" is missing.

Comment: @Alan: Ug you’re right. I can’t believe the human mind’s propensity for seeing what it thinks it is seeing rather than what it is there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) has a preconfigured [`CharMatcher`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) for [`whitespace()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#whitespace--). It works with unicode as well.

**Sample usage:**

```
System.out.println(CharMatcher.whitespace().removeFrom("H \ne\tl\u200al \to   "));
```

**Output:**

> Hello

The CharMatcher also has many other nice features, one of my favorites is the [`collapseFrom()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#collapseFrom%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20char%29) method, which replaces multiple occurences with a single character:

```
System.out.println(
    CharMatcher.whitespace().collapseFrom("H \ne\tl\u200al \to   ", '*'));
```

**Output:**

> H*e*l*l*o*

Comment: `CharMatcher.WHITESPACE` is now deprecated from Guava 20.0 onwards, `CharMatcher.whitespace()` is the replacement.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use `myString.replaceAll("\\s", "")`. But:

- note the comment about unicode whitespaces
- the above will remove newlines. If you don't want newlines removed, exclude them from the regex.

Comment: +1 This is the easiest way in Java to remove characters which we don't want. Notice, that your in your code, you only are removing the leading and trailing characters (See [trim JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29))

Comment: Correct, but for efficiency reasons you may want to use `myString.replaceAll("\\s+", "")` (notice the + sign) if you have any strings that contain a lot of concatenated white space characters.

Answer (score 4):

The reason to keep looking for different techniques is to find one that does what you really want.  For example, `trim()` only removes the whitespace from the beginning and end of the string.  To get the same effect with a regex, you have to do something like this:

```
s = s.replaceAll("^\\s+|\\s+$", "");
```

And then there's the matter of exactly which characters are removed.  Pre-Java 7, `\s` matches only ASCII whitespace characters, i.e.:

```
"[\\u0009\\u000A\\u000B\\u000C\\u000D\\u0020]"
```

...while (as Peter observed) `trim()` simple-mindedly removes all characters at or below codepoint 32 (`U+0020` in Unicode notation).  I suspect the thinking here was that the other characters are extremely unlikely to appear in a string anyway, and if they do, you probably want to get rid of them.  (It works for me, anyway. ☺)  But it's something you should be aware of.  Here's some code that demonstrates the difference between `trim()` and the regex approach:

```
String s = "\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0006\u0007"
         + "\u0008\u0009\n\u000B\u000C\r\u000E\u000F"
         + "\u0010\u0011\u0012\u0013\u0014\u0015\u0016\u0017"
         + "\u0018\u0019\u001A\u001B\u001C\u001D\u001E\u001F"
         + "\u0020\u00A0";
System.out.println(s.length());
System.out.println(s.trim().length());
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\s", "").length());
```

output:

```
34
1
28
```

The one remaining character in the second line of output is a non-breaking space (`U+00A0`, or "NBSP" henceforth).  There are a lot more whitespace characters once you get outside the ASCII range, but the one you're most likely to encounter is the NBSP.  Neither `trim()` nor the regex removed it, but watch what happens when you change the last line of code to this:

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?U)\\s", "").length());
```

...and run it under Java 7:

```
34
1
27
```

By adding the `(?U)`, I turned on `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASSES` mode, as mentioned by @tchrist in his comment.  NBSP *is* a whitespace character, no matter what `Character.isWhitespace()` says, but that doesn't mean you'll always want to include it in your whitespace matches.  That's why Guava (mentioned by @Sean) also includes a [BREAKING_WHITESPACE](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#BREAKING_WHITESPACE) CharMatcher.

In sum, to choose the right tool for removing whitespace, you need to know exactly which whitespace characters you want to remove, and exactly where you want to remove them from.  It's not all that complicated, but it's not as simple as legacy tools like `trim()` and StringTokenizer pretend it is, either.

Comment: as I see all of answers to my question goes another direction as I assumed, ... your answer put all together, that I really appreciate, now only +1

Answer (score 3):

Trim removes leading and trailing characters between ASCII 0 and ASCII 32.  This happens to remove most ASCII whitespaces but also removes all control characters. It doesn't remove them inside the String either.

```
for(int i=Character.MIN_CODE_POINT;i<=Character.MAX_CODE_POINT;i++)
  if(Character.isWhitespace(i))
    System.out.println(i);
```

prints

9
10
11
12
13
28
29
30
31
32
5760
6158
8192
8193
8194
8195
8196
8197
8198
8200
8201
8202
8232
8233
8287
12288

Comment: `control characters` are you meaning LineSeparator, EOF..., this area really isn't my cup of Java +1

Comment: I mean ^@, ^A, ^B, ^C to ^W, ^Y, ^Z ^[, ^\, ^], ^^ and ^-

Answer (score 1):

I was retyping some code from C# to Java - I needed to simulate XmlNode.OuterXml and XmlNode.InnerXml. For this I have used Transformer, however from some reason it does not recognize some whitespaces correctly even if you turn indentation off. So my other choice was to postprocess string containing carriage returns, linefeeds and tabs by regex using one of these two equivalent calls:

```
string.replaceAll("[\t\n\b\r\f]+ *", "");   
string.replaceAll("[\\s+ *", "");
```

both of these remove any whitespaces in a string and tab spaces as well. Hope it is at least little bit relevant. Second one is probably better choice

Answer (score 0):

String.replace(" ","");

(2) perhaps for performance tunning, other than that, I dunno